# 12.10 wont shut down

Tags: 12.10, shutdown

I have a brand new Acer Aspire V5 with Windows 7 and 12.10 alongside it. When I shut down 12.10 by clicking on shut down the system restarts, i.e. it shuts right down but instead of powering down it restarts from bios. It does this every time. The only way I can power down from 12.10 is by pressing and holding the power key. Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if run "sudo shutdown -h now" from the terminal? Also what happens if you unplug the laptop power cable and try to shutdown?

Comment: @coalaWeb: Hi there. I tried the command you'd mentioned in terminal but my laptop shuts down and reboots. It doesn't seem the solve the problem. Any idea as to what can be done?

Comment: Hi I have heard of people having problems with "-h" halt try "sudo poweroff" and if that doesn't work try your bios settings.

Comment: @user50652 Please, let us know if you solved the problem or it is still there. Thanks

Comment: ...or "sudo shutdown -P now"

Comment: go for the heart, try "sudo init 0", if that still reboots, check the contents of your /etc/rc0.d folder for the script "S90halt"
Disclaimer, the only Ubuntu machine I have in front of me is a 13.04 box, so file names might have changed, but runlevel 0 will always be your shutdown runlevel

Comment: This question is unclear, no further input was provided by OP.

Answer (score 0):

Hm config problem, look for the settings in `/etc/` for something like `pm` or `powermangment`. Also have a look in `/var/log/`.
Meanwhile you can use `sudo shutdown -P now` form the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening Terminal (Control + Alt/Option + T), then typing: 'sudo shutdown now' or 'sudo poweroff'.

Hope this helps!